# arrays of structs and pointers to them

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I have a struct with some members. In my main, the object i'm working on is defined like so

```
myStruct* s[1];
```

I then use it in a function like so

```
myFyn(myStruct **s){
  printf("%d",(*s)->member1);
}
myFun(&s[0]);
```

This works just fine and lets me print member1.
However, if I define mystruct like

```
mystruct* s[2];
myFun(&s[0]);
```

I'm met with segmentation faults every time i try to run the program.

Why is this? Is the something fundemental about pointers/arrays I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: Are you ever allocating anything? This "object" is an array of pointers.

Comment: No the structs are never initialized. s is just an array of pointers, as you said. But what i want to know is, why does one work when the other doesn't?

Comment: You need to provide a [MCVE], but if the `struct`s are not initialized, as you said in a comment, then this is undefined behavior: `printf("%d",(*s)->member1);`

Comment: Undefined behavior doesn't have to cause an error. It's undefined, so anything can happen, including something that appears to work. Your first example got lucky and didn't happen to indirect through an invalid address.